# Is there a way to map a tag in flex to components in multiple directories?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Given a flex application or module, you can specify a custom xml namespace as follows:

```
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:custom="custom.namespace.*">
```

We can then refer to mxml components in the directory custom/namespace/ using the custom tag.  For example, if I have the components Custom1 and Custom2 in the custom/namespace directory, I can refer to them like so:

```
<custom:Custom1/>
<custom:Custom2/>
```

Is there a way to map multiple directories onto the same tag?  That is, if I have components in a subdirectory of custom/namespace, like custom/namespace/sub with component SubCustom1, is there a way to modify the flex document so the custom tag can refer to SubCustom1?

Note that one workaround I found was to add a new tag for each directory (e.g. xmlns:custom.sub="custom.namespace.sub.*", and then:

```
<custom.sub:SubCustom1>
```

This solution seems like a kludge, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a custom namespace in flex you need to

1) Create a custom manifest file: e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<componentPackage>

    <component id="Accordion" class="mx.containers.Accordion"/>
    ....
```

2) Add something similar to the following to your flex-compiler.xml file:

```
<compiler>
    ...
      <namespaces>
         <!-- Specify a URI to associate with a manifest of components for use as MXML -->
         <!-- elements.                                                                -->
         <namespace>
            <uri>http://mycustomnamespace.com</uri>
            <manifest>custom-manifest.xml</manifest>
         </namespace>
      </namespaces>
</compiler>
```

You can read a more detailed explanation [here](http://blog.flashgen.com/2007/07/04/manifests-namespaces-and-flex-builder-2/).

This question was also answered [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=199432).

Answer (score 0):

The naming follows directly from the XML specification for namespaces. If you want to change `custom` to refer to the subdirectory change the namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:custom="custom.namespace.*"
```

to

```
xmlns:custom="custom.namespace.sub.*"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm asking if there's a way to map components from both directories, or two different directories (not necessarily nested), not if there's a way to change from one to the other.